# No localiza un valor en una funcion

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un formulario en el cual registro, edito y elimino. En la parte de registrar no marca error, pero cuando quiero editar algun valor del formulario me marca el siguiente erro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
case "mostrar": //Traera todos los datos y los separa en un JSON para que se puedan reutilizar
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente_x_id($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) > 0){
        foreach($datos as $row){
           $output["idPaciente"] = $row["idPaciente"];
           $output["nombrePac"] = $row["nombrePac"];
           $output["apellidoP"] = $row["apellidoP"];
           $output["apellidoM"] = $row["apellidoM"];
           $output["edad"] = $row["edad"];
           $output["Sexo_idSexo"] = $row["Sexo_idSexo"];
           $output["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"] = $row["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"];
           $output["telefono"] = $row["telefono"];
           $output["calleNumero"] = $row["calleNumero"];
           $output["colonia"] = $row["colonia"];
           $output["cp"] = $row["cp"];
           $output["ciudad"] = $row["ciudad"];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
     }

     $datos = $paciente->get_dolor_x_id($_POST["idDolor"]);
     if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) > 0){
        foreach($datos as $row){
           $output["idDolor"] = $row["idDolor"];
           $output["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"] = $row["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"];
           $output["sintomas"] = $row["sintomas"];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
     }

  break;
```

Y el codigo de las funciones es el siguiente:

```
public function get_paciente_x_id($idPaciente){ //"idPaciente" Mismo nombre que se tiene en la BD para llamar esa informacion
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE idPaciente = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idPaciente);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function get_dolor_x_id($idDolor){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dolor WHERE idDolor = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idDolor);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}
```

Este es el formulario, en el cual se registra el paciente, si regsitra todo, pero cuando quiero editar y quiero que toda la informacion que regsitre se muestre en el formulario, es cuando me marca los errores y no se exactamente el porque

```
<div id="modalpaciente" class="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="mdltitulo">Nuevo Registro</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post" id="paciente_form">
        <input type="hidden" id="idPaciente" name="idPaciente">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="nombrePac">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrePac" name="nombrePac" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="apellidoP">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoP" name="apellidoP" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="apellidoM">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoM" name="apellidoM" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="edad">Edad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="Sexo_idSexo">Sexo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Sexo_idSexo" name="Sexo_idSexo">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                            <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="2">Femenino</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="Ocupacion_idOcupacion">Ocupacion</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Ocupacion_idOcupacion" name="Ocupacion_idOcupacion">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                            <option value="1">Estudiante</option>
                            <option value="2">Profesionista</option>
                            <option value="3">Empleado</option>
                            <option value="4">Tecnico</option>
                            <option value="5">Otro</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="calleNumero">Calle y Numero</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="calleNumero" name="calleNumero" rows="3" placeholder="" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="colonia">Colonia</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colonia" name="colonia" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="cp">C.P</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <label class="col-12" for="Localizacion_idLocalizacion">Localizacion de Dolor</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Localizacion_idLocalizacion" name="Localizacion_idLocalizacion">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="1">Ojo izquierdo</option>
                        <option value="2">Ojo derecho</option>
                        <option value="3">Ambos</option>
                        <option value="4">Ninguno</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="sintomas">Sintomas</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="sintomas" name="sintomas" rows="3" placeholder="" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-default" type="button">Cerrar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" name="action" value="add" id="#">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

No se cual es la razon de porque me marca un erro en el valor de idDolor al momento de editar el formulario, si cuando lo regsitro no me marca algun error y si registra los datos correctamente

Comment: Difícil decir sin saber cual es la línea 43 y sin ver el formulario, pero así, a ciegas, diría que el POST no incluye ningún campo llamado ```idDolor``` y por tanto el fallo lo produce la línea que lo invoca: ```get_dolor_x_id($_POST["idDolor"]);```.  Puedes comprobar viendo si es parte del post añadiendo una verificación como esta antes de utilizarlo: ```isset($_POST['idDolor']) or die('idDolor no es parte del post')``` .

Comment: Ya lo edite y le agrege el formulario, espero que me pueda ayudar

Comment: Para hacer esto: `$_POST["idDolor"]` alguno de los elementos de tu `form` debe tener un `name="idDolor"` y además tener datos cuando el `form` es enviado. Sin embargo, no hay ningún elemento que se llame así.

Comment: Ahora ya se que el error esta en el formulario, gracias, el problema ahora seria en que parte puedo colocar el valor de `idDolor` ya que en la base de datos solo guarda un valor, ademas como lo puedo colocar para que sea igual a `<input type="hidden" id="idPaciente" name="idPaciente">`. Ya que ese es mi problema ahora, donde colocar ese valor o ese input

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en la línea:

```
$datos = $paciente->get_dolor_x_id($_POST["idDolor"]);
```

En el formulario que indicas no existe ningún campo llamado idDolor, por lo que cuando se envía por POST, $_POST["idDolor"] no existe.

Para solucionarlo, deberías añadir un campo en tu formulario:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12" for="idDolor">Ocupacion</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="idDolor" mame="idDolor">
            <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
            <option value="1">Dolor 1</option>
            <option value="2">Dolor 2</option>
            <option value="3">Dolor 3</option>
            <option value="etc">Etc.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahora ya se que el error esta en el formulario, gracias, el problema ahora seria en que parte puedo colocar el valor de `idDolor` ya que en la base de datos solo guarda un valor, ademas como lo puedo colocar para que sea igual a `<input type="hidden" id="idPaciente" name="idPaciente">`. Ya que ese es mi problema ahora, donde colocar ese valor o ese input

Comment: Cuando añades un campo del tipo 'hidden', como has hecho con 'idPaciente', tienes que añadir un atributo 'value' con el valor que le quieras dar al campo. Si 'idDolor' es un campo similar, tendrás que crearlo con otro campo 'hidden' en lugar de con un 'select' como puse en mi respuesta.